# Initializer lists

Tags: c++, initializer

point2d is a struct containing two double vars x and y.

```
Projectile::Projectile(Point2D p1, double x1, double y1){
    : xVel(x1), yVel(x1), pos.x(p1.x), pos.y(p1.y) { } 
}
```

Gives an error message saying expected expression at the :
Any ideas, not a matter of data type because all are double?

Comment: Can you paste the entire error message into the question please?

Answer (score 5):

You have an extra set of braces that you need to remove:

```
Projectile::Projectile(Point2D p1, double x1, double y1){ // <-- here
    : xVel(x1), yVel(x1), pos.x(p1.x), pos.y(p1.y) { } 
} // <-- here
```

Should be this instead:

```
Projectile::Projectile(Point2D p1, double x1, double y1)
    : xVel(x1), yVel(x1), pos.x(p1.x), pos.y(p1.y) { }
```

Comment: Good eye, I thought it looked weird but couldn't decide why. :)